# Django rest framework sorting in ascending and descending order

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my view code

```
class BlogListSerializerView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Blog
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

for sorting the client side request comes with two parameters, `'sorters[0][field]'` and `'sorters[0][dir]'`. Query param look like this `?page=1&size=15&sorters[0][field]=is_approved&sorters[0][dir]=asc`
I could add the first parameter in settings as follows

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'ORDERING_PARAM': 'sorters[0][field]'
}
```

and I have added ordering filter and ordering filter as follows to the view

```
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['category']
    ordering = ['-id']
```

Now it sorts the table but only in one direction, how can I sort it in ascending and descending order, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: put a `-` symbol as prefix in your query parameter

Comment: 'ORDERING_PARAM': '_sorters[0][field]' tried this way but not working even in one direction

Comment: example: `/api/foo/?sorters[0][field]=id` and ``/api/foo/?sorters[0][field]=-id``

Comment: Moreover, I am wondering why do you have such an ugly *ORDERING_PARAM* in the first place (no offense at all)